# Unimplemented feature in Ask Ubuntu

Tags: feature-request

I saw a user's Stack Overflow profile page and found an additional feature in it:

> [image]
>
> **top 0.95% overall**

When I click on the *top 0.95% overall* link, it redirects me to another page which shows the corresponding user's all time rank and all time reputation.

But when I see my Ask Ubuntu profile page, there was no such feature like the above. I also took a look at our mods' pages but it was still not there.

**My question:** Why is feature not enabled on Ask Ubuntu? What does the link actually refer to?

Comment: I might be going mad or something, but I'm *almost* pretty sure this was available before

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/31/alltime/askubuntu

Answer (score 2):

### Why is feature not enabled on Ask Ubuntu?

It's not enabled on *any* sites other than Stack Overflow, we're not missing out on much. It's likely only enabled on SO as that is the 'main' site. It's not a very important feature anyways..

### What does the link actually refer to?

That link just took you to the Reputation Leagues.

You can access it by going to [this page](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/31/month/askubuntu/), or clicking the **weekly / monthly / quarterly reputation leagues** link at the bottom of the [Users page's Reputation tab](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=reputation).

Click the link at the bottom:

> [image]

... it takes you to this page:

> [image]

Comment: What about the why part?